# mock function, and references to this function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I need to mock a function and all references which point to this function.

Example:

```
import mock

def do(msg):
    print(msg)

def foo():
    do('foo')

bar=foo

with mock.patch(__name__ + '.foo', lambda *args: do('mocked')):
    foo()
    bar()
```

the output is:

```
mocked
foo
```

But in my case I need to mock the real function, not just the name which points to the function implementation.

Background: I want to patch https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT

How can I get the desired output without using "bar".

```
mocked
mocked
```

Comment: You can't; `mock` just provides mechanisms for temporarily overriding what a name points to. You'll have to mock each name separately.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mocking `foo`, you could simply mock `do` instead.

```
with mock.patch(__name__ + '.do', lambda *args: print("mocked")):
    foo()
    bar()
```

Comment: sorry, I just needed `do()` since `print()` does not work in lambda().

Comment: What version of Python are you using? You can make `print` a function in Python 2.7 (just like in Python 3.x) using `from __future__ import print_function`. Oh, I see, `foo` has a different body. In that case, you may or may not be able to easily mock what is inside `foo`, rather than mocking `foo` itself.